# Eslint - File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

when I run `eslint package/**/*.ts **/*.ts`

get this warning:

```
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override

/home/njfamirm/One/package/util/index.d.ts
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override

/home/njfamirm/One/package/util/persian-number.d.ts
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override
```

My guess is that `*.ts` include `*.d.ts` file because I'm ignore `*.d.ts` format in .eslintignore

.eslintignore

```
*.js
*.mjs
*.map
*.d.ts
node_modules/
```

ts-lint.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ESNEXT",
    "module": "ESNEXT",
    "lib": ["ESNEXT", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "declaration": true,
    "composite": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["demo/**/*.ts", "package/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

[.eslintrc.yml](https://github.com/njfamirm/One/blob/next/.eslintrc.yaml)

[my Project](https://github.com/njfamirm/One)

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes in eslint command to enable glob pattern searching:

For example:

```
eslint "package/**/*.ts" "**/*.ts"
```